# FatalErrorException Laravel 5.3 Post Controllers

Tags: laravel, web, php-7

hi i have task title social network application using post and timeline 
i have some problem

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
        return redirect()->('home');
    }
}
```

this is my Post modle please check this code

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
 public function user (){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
$post = new Post();
```

To

```
$post = new Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Change:

`$post->body = $request['body'];`

to:

`$post->body = $request->get('body');`

2) This line: `$request->user()->posts()->save($post);` also seems all wrong.

In your User model you need to tell eloquent that a user has many posts

```
    public function posts()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Then that line in your controller for a user with `id = 1`; `$user = User::find(1)` becomes:

`$user->posts()->save($post)`

3)`return redirect()->('home');` has to be `return redirect()->route('home');`

4) Lastly, take some time to read the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3)